# What does `|-` mean in cloudformation Sub function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Consider example ([source](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-etl-orchestrator/blob/master/cloudformation/step-functions-resources.yaml))

```
  # State machine for testing Athena Runner
  AthenaRunnerTestETLOrchestrator:
    Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine"
    Properties:
      StateMachineName: AthenaRunnerTestETLOrchestrator
      DefinitionString:
        Fn::Sub:
          - |-
            {
              "StartAt": "Configure Athena Query",
              "States": {
                "Configure Athena Query":{
                  "Type": "Pass",
                  "Result": "{ \"AthenaQueryString\" : \"SELECT * FROM ${GlueTableName} limit 10;\", \"AthenaDatabase\": \"${GlueDatabaseName}\", \"AthenaResultOutputLocation\": \"${AthenaResultOutputLocation}\", \"AthenaResultEncryptionOption\": \"${AthenaResultEncryptionOption}\"}",
                  "Next": "Execute Athena Query"
                },
                "Execute Athena Query":{
                  "Type": "Task",
                  "Resource": "${AthenaRunnerActivityArn}",
                  "End": true
                }
              }
            }
          - {
            GlueDatabaseName: !Ref MarketingAndSalesDatabaseName,
            GlueTableName: !Ref MarketingTableName,
            AthenaRunnerActivityArn: !Ref AthenaRunnerActivity,
            AthenaResultOutputLocation: !Sub "s3://${SourceDataBucketName}/athena-runner-output/",
            AthenaResultEncryptionOption: "SSE_S3"
        }
      RoleArn: !GetAtt StateExecutionRole.Arn
```

Function `Sub` should received array of params: `source` and `replacements`, ut why `|-` is passed here? Is it `yaml` or aws `Sub` function feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`|-` is a `yaml` feature than means a multi-line string with linebreaks preserved and without a linebreak at the end:

[How do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines#answer-21699210)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's `yaml` feature. I refer to the [YAML-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), as it said:

> Strings do not require quotation marks. There are two ways to write multi-line strings, one preserving newlines (using the | character) and one that folds the newlines (using the > character), both followed by a newline character.

And refer to [How do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines), we can get

> Use >- or |- instead if you don't want a linebreak appended at the end.

So, `|-` just converts this part to `string`.

```
            {
              "StartAt": "Configure Athena Query",
              "States": {
                "Configure Athena Query":{
                  "Type": "Pass",
                  "Result": "{ \"AthenaQueryString\" : \"SELECT * FROM ${GlueTableName} limit 10;\", \"AthenaDatabase\": \"${GlueDatabaseName}\", \"AthenaResultOutputLocation\": \"${AthenaResultOutputLocation}\", \"AthenaResultEncryptionOption\": \"${AthenaResultEncryptionOption}\"}",
                  "Next": "Execute Athena Query"
                },
                "Execute Athena Query":{
                  "Type": "Task",
                  "Resource": "${AthenaRunnerActivityArn}",
                  "End": true
                }
              }
            }
```